# repeating specific rows in array n times

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a huge numpy array with 15413 rows and 70 columns. The first column represents the weight (so if the first element in a row is n, that row should be repeated n times.

I tried with numpy.repeat but I don’t think it’s giving me the correct answer because np.sum(chain[:,0]) is not equal to len(ACT_chain)

```
ACT_chain = []
for i in range(len(chain[:,0])):
    chain_row = chain[i]
    ACT_chain.append(chain_row)
    if int(chain[:,0][i]) > 1:
        chain_row = np.repeat(chain[i], chain[:, 0][i], axis=0) 
        ACT_chain.append(chain_row)
```

For example, running this code with this sample array

```
chain = np.array([[1, 5, 3], [2, 2, 1], [3, 0, 1]])
```

gives

```
[array([1, 5, 3]), array([2, 2, 1]), array([[2, 2, 1],
   [2, 2, 1]]), array([3, 0, 1]), array([[3, 0, 1],
   [3, 0, 1],
   [3, 0, 1]])]
```

but the output I expect is

```
array([[1, 5, 3], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1], [3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Can't you test this on a smaller array where you can actually see the result?  Don't expect us to construct test case(s).  That's your job!

Comment: @hpaulj, II've edited the question with a sample case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `repeat` here, without the iteration.

```
np.repeat(chain, chain[:, 0], axis=0)

array([[1, 5, 3],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [3, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you @user3483203. For my huge array mentioned above, 
chain = np.repeat(chain, float(chain[:, 0]), axis=0) gives me an error

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/lt/h3lspb0d7jq02k2kwxwk8gsh0000gn/T/ipykernel_9095/496964247.py in <module>
----> 1 chain = np.repeat(chain, float(chain[:, 0]), axis=0)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

I solved the typeError by converting the whole array to int

```
chain = chain.astype(int)
```